# Create or query a Dynamics 365 task associated to a Contact

Tags: node.js, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

Using [dynamics-web-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamics-web-api) in Node.js

I want to get (and ultimately create) tasks associated with a lead or contact in MS Dynamics 365.  Using js.  However, I cannot figure out how to match a Contact ID with a Task's ID.  How can I match or see things that are associated like this?

```js
var dynamicsWebApi = MyDynamicsContextGetter();

var filters = `emailaddress1 eq '${email.trim()}' 
    and firstname eq '${firstName.trim()}'
    and lastname eq '${lastName.trim()}'`;

dynamicsWebApi.retrieveRequest({
    collection: "contacts",
    select: ["fullname", "emailaddress1", "company"],
    filter: filters,
    top: 1,
    count: true
}).then(function (response) {
    var count = response.oDataCount;
    var records = response.value;
    var topContactId = records.length > 0 ? records[0].contactid : null;
    if(count !== 0) {
        dynamicsWebApi.retrieveRequest({
            collection: 'tasks',
            filter: 'regardingobjectid_contact/contactid eq ' + topContactId,
            top: 5,
            count: true
        }).then(function(response) {


        // THIS VALUE IS ALWAYS 0 FOR ME 
        console.log("response", response.oDataCount); 


    }).catch(function (error) {
        res.send(500);
    });
}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks right, except the below line, try this:

```
        filter: "regardingobjectid_contact/contactid eq guid'" + topContactId + "'",
```